# How to solve a never ending loop of login screens when trying to OAuth in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, oauth

Trying to learn oauth for my chrome extension using identity api.
I have uploaded code to 
https://github.com/Sandeep3005/learn-oauth-extension

**Issue :** 
When background file runs -  it opens a new tab with Gmail login page.But even I provide right credentials login page keep appear again and again and I have to force quit Chrome.

A solution provided at 
[Stack Overflow Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141573/chrome-identity-getauthtoken-not-working) - mentions this occurs when app-ID in chrome is different at app-ID in https://console.developers.google.com.
But I checked and rechecked it.Both values of app-ID is exact.
Can anybody guide me on this.

**manifest.json**

```
     {
       "manifest_version": 2,
       "name": "outh-test-2",
       "short_name": "outh-test-2",
       "description": "Description for outh-test-2",
       "version": "1.0",
       "background": { "scripts": [ "background.js" ], "persistent": true },
       "content_scripts": [
        {
           "run_at": "document_end",
           "matches": [
              "https://www.dominos.co.in/",
              "https://en.wikipedia.org/*"
            ],
            "js": [ "content.js" ]
        }
       ],
       "permissions": [
          "identity"
       ],
       "oauth2": {
          "client_id": "574710815026-blt94u58ie7jqqanuc73b49mdaqrp9j4.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "scopes": [
            "http://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
          ]
       },
       "key":"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmRBFelCyG27kHcy38C/bZXggBPDV3JyKnsunJDfHotUG9QQI6Z+KzoeEdCKK/GvQe7AGTNkkr3FUATGmR1b5MbjzTx90qzg6xsrXSU7mqBgJwYPny+PW46pGRwMSz4FEcLO1vUKD9kIhpSzi+0RJv1IwDx6/SNeQzOxXR5B7dWXTKtbiD9f9Rd5yj9Qfy1Q76iIc8P6afpO1DgT960+yZV4+12tCoC+GZILvK3GBwC0vhkeVsIMWaNkIIzC/0PcbLis2HrfZz6iHcetcv4aY6MAIfQWBxaFbDiXXIhXSvi9zO00w/mc9hLxls4fcivXZdEowgEu0UV4+EJuzL35s2wIDAQAB"
    }
```

**background.js**

```
console.log('Welcome to background Page');

console.log('chrome Identity  = ', chrome.identity);

chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function (token) {
 if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
  callback(chrome.runtime.lastError);
  return;
 }
 access_token = token;
});
```

**Steps I followed**
1. Created basic chrome extension with client-id and key values missing

2.Upload ziped extension file to 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard

3.Copied public-key and item-id.

4.Create new project at google developer console

5.
    a)Create credentials for OAuth Client ID
    b)Picked Chrome App as application type
    c)Inserted Item-ID I got from webstore developer dashboard in application-ID text field
    d)Got Client-ID in return.

6) Copied this client-ID in manifest.json file and also inserted pulic key here.

Wrote code for background.js and ran extension on chrome and boom - I am inside a loop where google ask for email password again, again and again...

Please guide me on this

Comment: Are you signed into Chrome before you run your extension?

Comment: yes i m signed in - before I run extension

Comment: Try with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` in the `scopes` section of `oauth2`. Notice that it is `https`, not `http`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) states, the scope you need is:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

You wrote `http://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` but it must be `https`.