# XMLHttpRequest in Chrome locks up browser

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have the following code (I don't recommend running it):

```
     let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
     req.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
     req.onload = function() {
        console.log('response:', req.response);
     };
     req.send();
```

What happens is this opens up a new tab, and this tab completely steals all the focus. I can't use any of the other Chrome tabs, it quickly switches back to the auth tab. And if I log-in with the auth tab, it just reloads the same auth tab, and I am back to square one.

The token is acquired via this call:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function (token) {}):
```

Has anyone seen this horrible problem? I can't get Chrome to stop making an auth request to the url in the screenshot. It keeps stealing the focus, and forcing me to login over and over again.

From what I can tell, it's actually this call this brings to me to the black hole authentication tab:

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken()
```

This didn't use to happen, but seems like it started happening after I added this to my manifest.json file:

```
  "oauth2": {
    "client_id": "5461xxx462-7gebv033e9csxxxxg5f6ggu22rju9374.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo", // added this line
      "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo.picture", // and added this line
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },
```

[image]

The old login screen looks like this, and this worked really nicely:

[image]

I am currently fairly certain that these two lines in the scopes array are what are causing the problem:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo.picture"
```

what do I do?

Comment: Did you enable the affected APIs in Google APIs Console for your project?

Comment: I enabled IAM (Identity) API...I am not sure what other APIs to enable

Comment: I use the google drive api with the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file" and encounter the same problem. My key, client_id and app id are all correct. Even when the user is already logged, the login page appears and the user should login to allow my app to access the google drive files.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before but it was months ago. If I recall correctly, it ended up being that the client_id was invalid. Double check your oauth client_id to make sure you're using the correct one.